# Add Content-Length header to Google Endpoints app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm building a Google Endpoints app that based on some parameters, returns a json response. The endpoints will mostly be used on an Android/iOS app and because there is the need to have a progressbar to display the current progress of the request, i would need to incorporate a Content-Length in the response header. I've read the GAE documentation and it tells me that i have to add

```
    <static-files>
  <include path="/my_static-files" >
    <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://example.org" />
  </include>
</static-files>
```

in my appengine-web.xml file. I have done that, but there is no such header showing up when looking for it using postman.

My appengine-web.xml file:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>myApplicationId</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <basic-scaling>
        <max-instances>15</max-instances>
    </basic-scaling>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
    <static-files>
        <include  path="/WEB-INF/*">
            <http-header name="Content-Length" value="1761" />
        </include>
    </static-files>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I'm guessing that i have the "path" parameter wrong, but the documentation does not help me find the correct information to put there. Is this only relevant for accessing static files ? If so, how can i add such a header to a request that is made like this:

```
https://xyz.appspot.com/_ah/api/myApi/v7/blabla/
```

Comment: The documentation the i saw was: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref#include_exclude

Comment: App engine is already setting a correct `Content-Length` header, is it enough? and you cannot replace it with incorrect one

Comment: I do not see a Content-Length header in the response i get from the app. Also reading https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/how-requests-are-handled#headers_added_or_replaced , they say that

Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding

The server always ignores the Content-Length header returned by the application. It will either set Content-Length to the length of the body (after compression, if compression is applied), or delete Content-Length, and use chunked transfer encoding (adding a Transfer-Encoding: chunked header). Am i misunderstanding something ?

Comment: how do you check for the header? do you deploy it to a real app engine server, or just checking with emulator? if latter, I don't think it set any header

Comment: http://imgur.com/li4u0ba -> I have the app engine deployed. Here are the response headers i get from a response made with Postman.

Comment: oh, that's interesting, I've just tried with different apps and found that this header is skipped for apps with custom domain _and_ ssl enabled. I believe it's a bug in Google Frontend, I suggest to send a bug report.